# "string s = null" is technically incorrect?

Tags: c#, syntax, null

**Please let me know if this is in the wrong place, or let me know a better place for it.**

**This question is not about the syntax, more the idea behind it.**

**I would like to know what `null` is essentially, or isn't as the case may be**

First off, I just want to clarify exactly what `null` is. By my understanding, `null` is 
*technically* nothing. So the statement

```
string s = null;
```

is technically incorrect? You are assigning a variable *no value* but a variable can't not have a value? Am I correct in thinking this?

My idea of `null` is that it's kind of like thinking, **"If I go and get a drink of water, I will need a cup to put the water in". `null` is the space in which the data will be placed in, but the space doesn't exist yet.** Following this idea:

```
string s = "";
```

would be more appropriate, no? And along this thought (though a bit less confusing)

```
int n = 0;
```

follows the same idea, where `0` is a value, but the value of `0` is nothing?

Comment: This depends on what language you're working in, so it would be very helpful if you tagged your question with the relevant language.

Comment: Please tag this with an appropriate language.

Answer (score 2):

The original line of code is quite valid.  In C#, any reference type variable can have no value, i.e. it refers to no object.  `null` is quite different to an empty string.  Consider a variable of some other type, e.g. `Form`.  What would be the equivalent of an empty string then?  A `null` in C# is basically the same as a NULL in a database.

Value types are a but different.  Because reference type variables contain a reference, it is possible for them to refer to no object.  Value type variables, on the other hand, contain a value and so cannot be `null`.  A `struct` or `enum` is a value type and a `class` or `delegate` is a reference type.  So, if a variable on the stack contains the value zero then, for a reference type that means no object, i.e. `null`, and for a value type that means the default value for that type, e.g. zero for numbers, `false` for `bool` and `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime`.

C# references are basically tarted-up pointers.  Just as in C/C++ a pointer can be null to point to no object, so a C# reference-type variable can be null to refer to no object.  In the case of strings, an empty string is an object and is very different to null.  An empty balloon is still a balloon and very different to no balloon at all.

Comment: So just to clarify, `null` is "no balloon at all" and the line `string s = null;` is saying there could be a balloon? The theory behind it is a bit mind bending...

Comment: It's important to remember that OOP is based on the behaviour of real-world objects.  You are a person and, for this example, I will assume that you are unmarried. If we were going to represent you in C# then you would be an instance of the `Person` class. What would be the value of your `Spouse` property? Would it be an empty `Person`? No, it would be no `Person` at all, which is represented by `null`.

Comment: Haha didn't think of it that way.

Comment: Theoretically, if you run out of memory before that reference is filled, would that cause issues? Probably not, because it's a reference to another property, so it won't take up memory, just fill itself with a piece of memory already allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion likely lies in the difference between **reference types** and **value types**.

```
void Foo() {
    string s = null;
}
```

This does not create a `string`. Instead, `s` is a *reference* to a string. However, `s` is currently referring to (or pointing to, in C terminology) nothing.

```
s --->  [nothing]
```

Now when we do this:

```
s = "Stack Overflow";
```

we are making `s` refer to that string. `s` itself doesn't *contain* the string.

```
s ----> "Stack Overflow"
```

Note that `""` itself *is* a string, and *does exist*

```
s ----> ""
```

<sub>Strings are actually a bad example because of [string interning](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html).</sub>

---

Value types on the other hand line up with your confusion.

An `int` for example, *must* have a value. If you don't assign it one, it will (generally) take the default value of `0`.

See more:

- [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is not wrong as much as it is redundant because `null` is the default value of `string`
as `int num = 0` is redundant because 0 is the default value of `int`

If you need to initialize your string then you should go for `string s = ""` or my personal favorite `string s = string.Empty`

Comment: That is in correct.  Yes, `null` is the default value for a reference type but the compiler still requires that you initialise a variable explicitly in order to use its value.  The compiler will not just assume that you meant for a variable to be `null` if you don't specify it.  In short, you must set the value of a variable before using a variable's value, even if that value is `null`.

Comment: That's true for a local variable, but not for a field.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, true. In the case of local variables, the compiler says "If you didn't set the variable to anything then maybe you meant it to be null or maybe you just forgot to initialise it, so I'm going to make sure". In the case of member variables though, there's no way for the compiler to know, for any particular use of the field, that some other method that set the field wasn't called earlier. As such, it just has to say "if you didn't initialise that variable when you should have then it's your own stupid fault; I can only do so much to save you from yourself"!

Answer (score 0):

Null means nothing. 0 is a value, but null means that there is no value. Actually in C#:

```
 string s=null;
```

means that instance of the class string is null and has no value.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `string s` is just a variable pointing to a place in memory which was allocated for you.

- `string s = null;` Is allocating a variable but it is not pointng to a place in your memory.
- `string s = ";` micht be the same but it is pointing to a slot in your memory containing a iteral with an empty string.

I hope that made the problem a bit more clear.